# show/hide a div based on input change

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to show/hide a div based on change in input. I need anything greater than 0 to show my div. If it's 0 the div goes hidden. Below is the current HTML I got for that input which comes by 0 value in default. I need my "additionalInfo" div to stay hidden at 0 by default and only show or any value greater than 0. Can you please help me with an example specific to the code I provided below?

```html
<input type="text" class="NetscapeFix CalTicketQuantity form-control" name="tix_quantity" id="tix_quantity2" value="0" size="4" maxlength="4" onchange="calculate(this.form);">

<div class="additionaInfo">Div content will go here</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're working with digit values, your input should probably be of `number` type.

```js
// Your listen for value changes in your input
document.querySelector('#your-input').addEventListener('change', function calculate(e) {
const div = document.querySelector('#div-to-show-hide');
// Your grab the input value and test your condition
    if (Number(e.target.value) > 0)
    div.style.display = 'block';
  else
    div.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="your-input" class="NetscapeFix CalTicketQuantity form-control" name="tix_quantity" id="tix_quantity2" value="0" size="4" maxlength="4">

<div id="div-to-show-hide" class="additionaInfo" style="display:none;">Div content will go here</div>
```

Comment: Great, this works perfect. Thanks so much. Can you help me add animation to the DIV that would show up from hidden to block ?